# how to connect to external kafka server with "cacerts" file using python

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I am able to connect to my local kafka server with python kafka package. 
however I am not able to connect to external ssl enabled kafka server.

Whereas my java code is able to communicate with the same server using these parameters:

```
props.put("security.protocol", kafkaProtocol);
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, kafkaProtocol);
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, kafkaCertLocation);
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, kafkaCertPassword);
```

I don't know what exactly the equivalent parameters in python kafka package. 
Can some suggest me on this immediately.

I have tried this code:

```
producer = KafkaProducer(value_serializer=lambda m: json.dumps(m).encode('utf-8'),
                         bootstrap_servers='YYYYY.KAKFASERVER.com:9094',
                         security_protocol='SSL',
                         ssl_certfile='cacerts',
                         ssl_password='xxxxxxx')
```

I am getting the following error message:

> failed to connect to YYYYY.KAKFASERVER.com:9094 unknown error (_ssl.c:3715)